# {ClientError}An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: Invalid InstanceProfile

Tags: terraform, boto3, amazon-emr, terraform-provider-aws

I deployed using Terraform an IAM Role to be used in EMR:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "emr_assume_role" {
  statement {
    sid     = "EMRAssume"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "my_emr_ec2_instance_role" {
  name               = "my_emr_ec2_instance_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.emr_assume_role.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "emr_ec2_instances_policy" {
  name    = "emr_ec2_instances_policy"
  policy  = file("${path.module}/my/path/my_emr_instance_role_policy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.my_emr_ec2_instance_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.emr_ec2_instances_policy.arn
}
```

Then when I try to run [`run_job_flow()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow) method from boto3 like this:

```
client.run_job_flow(
    Name="EMR",
    LogUri=logs_uri,
    ReleaseLabel='emr-6.2.0',
    Instances=instances,
    VisibleToAllUsers=True,
    Steps=steps,
    BootstrapActions=ba,
    Applications=[{'Name': 'Spark'}],
    ServiceRole='my_service_role_emr',
    JobFlowRole='my_emr_ec2_instance_role',
    Tags=tags)
```

But I straight-away receive the following error message:

```
{ClientError}An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: Invalid InstanceProfile my_emr_ec2_instance_role
```

How to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing my experience hoping to help someone else, please share yours if different.

In my case a **first mistake** was with the `identifiers` field, which should have had `"ec2.amazonaws.com"` as value, so the `aws_iam_policy_document` block would get:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "emr_assume_role" {
  statement {
    sid     = "EMRAssume"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Another issue** is relative to the `Instance Profile` which would have been automatically created if the Role would have been generated from the AWS Console, but Terraform doesn't provide it automatically. So in Terraform this block of code should fix the problem:

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "emr_ec2_instance_profile" {
  name = aws_iam_role.my_emr_ec2_instance_role.name
  role = aws_iam_role.my_emr_ec2_instance_role.name
}
```